How can I add text to a data point on a d3 graph?
I am using d3 to try and create a line graph with text on one of the lines data points. Here is a jsfiddle of my unsuccessful attempt at doing this:
https://jsfiddle.net/pz2afemd/
var y = [5,6,8,4]

var data = [];
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  data.push({"date": x[i], "value": y[i]});
}

// 2. Use the margin convention practice 
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height


// 5. X scale will use the index of our data
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.min(x) , d3.max(x)]) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

// 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number 
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(y)]) // input 
    .range([height, 0]); // output 

// 7. d3's line generator
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); }) // set the x values for the line generator
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.value); }) // set the y values for the line generator 

// 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
var svg = d3.select("#my_chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// 3. Call the x axis in a group tag
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

// 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

// 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line 
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
    .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator 

svg.append("text")
  .attr("y", line.y)//magic number here
  .attr("x", line.x)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr("class", "myLabel")//easy to style with CSS
  .text("I'm a label");

The last append on the graph is the text. However I am having trouble placing the text on a (x,y) datapoint on the line. Instead the text is placed above the y axis. Is there a way position the text on one of the lines data point?

I think you are doing it right, we need to make sure to use the existing line data and position:
// Append the label
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", xScale(data[data.length - 1].date))  // Position at the x value of the last data point
    .attr("y", yScale(data[data.length - 1].value)) // Position at the y value of the last data point
    .attr("dy", -10)  // Adjust vertical position
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  // Center the text
    .text("custom Label");  // Text content of the label

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxqbfywo/5/
